# Android image file not created

Tags: android, image, file, android-asynctask, save

I created this AsyncTask to download an image and save it to the phone.  If the image already exists is should just skip the code that downloads the image, yet every time it gets to f.exists() it's false even when the image has already been saved previously.  Why would this be?

```
private class fanartDownloader extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        //First argument is image url and the second is the show id
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            String fanartUrl = args[0];
            fanartUrl = fanartUrl.substring(0, fanartUrl.length() - 4);
            //Add proper end for small image
            fanartUrl += SMALL_FANART_URL_END;
            try {
                String path = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().toString();
                path = path + "/" + args[1] + "/";
                File f = new File(path, "fanart.jpg");
                if (f.exists()) {

                }
                else {
                    f.mkdir();
                    URL url_value = new URL(fanartUrl);
                    Bitmap fanart = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url_value.openConnection().getInputStream());
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(path);
                    fanart.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Now I've solved the issue with this slightly different iteration:

```
private class fanartDownloader extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        //First argument is image url and the second is the show id
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            String fanartUrl = args[0];
            fanartUrl = fanartUrl.substring(0, fanartUrl.length() - 4);
            //Add proper end for small image
            fanartUrl += SMALL_FANART_URL_END;
            try {
                String file = args[1] + "_" + "fanart.jpg";
                String path = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().toString();
                path = path + "/" + file;
                File f = new File(path);
                if (f.exists()) {

                }
                else {
                    URL url_value = new URL(fanartUrl);
                    Bitmap fanart = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url_value.openConnection().getInputStream());
                    FileOutputStream out = getApplicationContext().openFileOutput(file, MODE_PRIVATE);
                    fanart.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Does anyone know why the first AsyncTask wouldn't work?

Comment: Does your app have permission to read and write to the SD card?

Comment: Yes `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` has been added to the manifest

Comment: Are you sure that the path is correct and the files are *actually* there?